# Switching between AC and DC input

Tags: dc, ac, ac-dc

Let's say I need to power a 9v device with an input power source that is either AC or DC and changes almost randomly. Is there any way for me to detect in a circuit when AC changes to DC or vice-versa and have the circuit switch itself? Ideally I'd like to be able to design two circuits that would maintain power to the device constantly regardless of the input type and voltage.

Is there some circuit wizardry I can do that would be a pseudo switch or is it not possible?

I'm more a software guy but I'd like to know a bit more about hardware, hence the almost noobish question.

Comment: A bridge rectifier can accept AC or DC of either polarity. Do you need anything more than this?

Comment: I hope you're not refering to wall socket AC (120 or 240 V) and some low voltage DC switching. If so, the answers here will release lots of magic smoke for your application (i.e. fry your stuff). Please specify your multiple inputs more specifically.

Answer (score 2):

The wizardry lies in using diodes in series to be able to put DC power supplies in parallel without damaging them from (even tiny) differences in voltage, just like on the following diagram. [image]

Then from there, you can replace the second power supply by a rectifier which converts AC (of appropriate voltage amplitude, use transformers upstream if not the case - or DC/DC converters downstream) to DC. Note that in this setup, D2 wouldn't be necessary as the rectifier already prevents current from going upstream.

[image]

For the explanation, diodes are analog OR gates: whichever has the higher applied voltage puts the diode in conduction, and the other prevents current from going in the other power supply.

**Warning:** for this to work, at least one of the power supplies needs to have a floating ground (be isolated from eachother) or have the exact same ground, otherwise they're going to force eachother to different potentials and result in shortcircuits.

Finally, you may want to place a voltage regulator after the two power supplies because of the rectifier (which would allow you to place the battery straightaway as PS1).

However, why not use mains-DC adapters that lie around to take care of the AC/DC conversion, and just make sure your battery + regulator and that adapter are put in parallel with diodes?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the diagrams. It's a good call but considering there's a power source there it just needs to be tamed, I'd like to use that to my advantage if possible and if not possible- understand why.

Comment: If you really have a power source that switches randomly between AC and DC (which is a really odd one), just put a rectifier at the end. In DC it would not change anything (just the voltage drop of 2 diodes), and in AC you would end up with DC.

Answer (score 1):

If you have AC then feed it through a diode to convert to DC. You can do the same with the DC. If you use full wave rectifiers both AC and "any-polarity" DC will work. The two can be combined into one circuit and whichever power source produces the larger voltage will supply power to your 9V device. Also consider that you may need to use a voltage regulator.

If the two power sources are independent and galvanically isolated it's easy. If the two power sources are not galvanically isolated then you need to think a little harder about how this is achieved. I have no way of knowing of course.

Comment: I appreciate the question is lacking specificity but it's something I have thought about for quite some time but never knew where to start

Comment: diodes are your friends (except when they decide to demodulate the local AM broadcast on your new low noise amp you've just designed lol).